# A "version" of the bible with sentence structure written in English but retaining most of the original untranslated "nouns/verbs/adjectives"?

Tags: bible

Is there a "version" of the bible that has it's sentence structure written in English, yet retaining most of the original untranslated "nouns/verbs/adjectives" ?

Ok this is quite hard to explain, I'm not sure if anyone knows what I'm trying to say, but for example:

> **[John 1:19 (NIV)](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%201&version=NIV#en-NIV-26064)**
>
> Now this was John’s testimony when the Jewish leaders[c] in Jerusalem sent priests and Levites to ask him who he was.
>
> [c]: The Greek term traditionally translated the Jews (hoi Ioudaioi) refers here and elsewhere in John’s Gospel to those Jewish leaders who opposed Jesus
>
> **[John 1:51 (NIV)](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%201&version=NIV#en-NIV-26096)**
>
> He then added, “Very truly I tell you,[i] you[j] will see ‘heaven open, and the angels of God ascending and descending on’ the Son of Man.”
>
> [i]: The Greek is plural.
>
> [j]: The Greek is plural.
>
> **[Luke 11:34 (NIV)](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke+11&version=NIV#en-NIV-25440)**
>
> Your eye is the lamp of your body. When your eyes are healthy,[g] your whole body also is full of light. But when they are unhealthy,[h] your body also is full of darkness.
>
> [g]: The Greek for healthy here implies generous.
>
> [h]: The Greek for unhealthy here implies stingy.

It is somewhat like the information in **[c]**, **[i]**, and **[j]**. But now only certain words are annotated. I believe this information is useful for in-dept Bible studying and I was wondering if there is a resource which shows more of these information.

In fact, if "hard-core" makes sense, I would like a "hard-core" resource.

**++ Update: ++**

To add to the answers, I've found a pretty good interlinear at http://www.phpbible.org/

Comment: There is no such thing as "untranslated" words. Out of dictionaries in any two languages only a handful of words will have anything resembling one-on-one equivalents in the other language. The score is worse for phrases. Of you want "untranslated" you will have to learn the source language.

Comment: @Caleb You have misunderstood me. When I say the "untranslated" words, I mean the "source" words. In other words, the "not translated" words. Take a look at the link in a_hardin's answer.

Comment: Saws so I have. On that case I thinky this is called "interlinear" and yes they exist. More when I'm on a computer. And sorry!

Comment: @Caleb don't worry about it =)

Comment: You can get singular / plural distinctions from the AV (King James) which uses the English thee / ye  conventions.

Comment: @Ollie thx for the info!

Comment: One problem is that words do not map one to one. Both Hebrew and Greek are inflected language, Hebrew in a very different way to English. Often one English word might cover the stem and others various parts of the inflection. The same goes for prefixes and suffixes. In Hebrew some prepositions and conjunctions are also prefixes. The word orders are very different resulting in this pieces not being next to each other. Also Hebrew morphology can pack a lot of things into a single word that English cannot.

Comment: Yes interlinear is really the best solution for this. It's kind of a parallel text with the two texts alternating line by line rather than page by page.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want "hard-core", you might want to look into the [Apostolic Bible](http://apostolicbible.com/):

[image]

It's a solid resource for the **New Testament**.

However, as @Ollie Jones mentioned, the Old Testament for this is based on the Septuagint--an ancient Greek translation--rather than the original Hebrew.  Because of that, it's not quite as reliable as going straight to the source.  (In some situations it can be quite a ways off.)

For the Old Testament, I like to use the [Online Hebrew Interlinear Bible](http://www.scripture4all.org/OnlineInterlinear/Hebrew_Index.htm)

[image]

It should be noted that there is a corresponding online version of the Greek for the New Testament, but I prefer the Apostolic Bible for the NT.

Comment: This is an interlinear Hebrew Bible with the Septaguint--the Greek translation of the Hebrew from antiquity.

Comment: Thanks.  It's better now that I figured out the Septuagint bit.  [Related question](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/2248/can-we-trust-the-septuagint)

Comment: @Richard, Btw, regarding your last paragraph, why did you prefer the Apostolic for the NT instead of the Greek Interlinear?

Comment: @Pacerier Three years ago, when I answered the question, I think I had a better reason.  However, my memory says that it was just personal preference.  I just liked the Apostolic better.  It seems like there was an online Greek interlinear, but the format was a little more annoying (or something like that).  Again, I'm sure I had a better reason than that, though.

Comment: @Richard, Thanks for the response. If you recall/reevaluate this again in the future, please feel free to include the analysis here. Also, the free pdf version I downloaded from http://www.apostolicbible.com/text.htm seems complete. Is there a difference between the free version and the paid version?

Comment: @Pacerier I bought the hard-copy of the Apostolic and it seems identical to the free PDF.

Answer (score 4):

The Amplified Bible is intended to do exactly what you're seeking. More information about it is available at http://www.biblegateway.com/versions/Amplified-Bible-AMP/ and the actual text is available online via the same site.

Answer (score 3):

Young's Literal Translation is very good to keep all the original tense and word usage found in the Greek and Hebrew text, but still contains a sentence structure quite similar to what we commonly use today. You will find some instance of slightly different sentence structure, but for someone seeking to do in-depth study would find it an invaluable resource.

Young's Literal Translation was compiled in 1898 by Robert Young. You can find it in almost any Bible Book Store or online at [Blue Letter Bible](http://www.blueletterbible.org), [Bible Gateway](http://www.biblegateway.com/versions/Youngs-Literal-Translation-YLT-Bible/), or [Bible.cc](http://yltbible.com/). You can also order it directly from [Baker Books](http://www.bakerbooks.com/ME2/Audiences/dirmod.asp?sid=0477683E4046471488BD7BAC8DCFB004&nm=&type=PubCom&mod=PubComProductCatalog&mid=BF1316AF9E334B7BA1C33CB61CF48A4E&tier=3&id=CACBF9441CD1495ABDDA05BA2D23926D).

Answer (score 2):

Here's an excellent resource that I use all the time:
http://www.onlinebible.net/

It really isn't "online" in the sense that it uses a web site.  It's a PC software package.

It has the KJV with word by word references to Strong's lexicon.  Each Hebrew, Greek, and Aramaic verb is parsed.  You can also get the Greek Testament with Strong's markup, as well as the Septaguint.

(If you are to understand the parsing, you probably need to know the names of the Greek tenses (aorist, perfect, etc) and the Hebrew voices (hitpael, etc).)

You can get many public domain translations in many languages for no fee.  For example, you can get the Vulgate, a Hebrew translation, and Luther's Bible (in German).

If you pay a small amount, you can get several modern translations, including NIV, NRSV and even Eugene Peterson's paraphrase called The Message.

Blessings on your study.

Answer (score 2):

I use e-Sword which gives me KJV with Strong's Concordance as well as the Greek with Strong's.  So, you can just click on the Strong's numbers beside the words, look at the KJV Concordance to see how it's translated in the KJV, also get Strong's definition and other helps as well.

e-Sword is the best Bible software money can't buy.  (It's free.)  e-sword.net.

I would also suggest the Analytical-Literal Translation of the New Testament.  We basically used it as the answer key when we were translating Greek.

This is an interesting chart that compares word-for-word to thought-for-thought translations:  http://www.apbrown2.net/web/TranslationComparisonChart.htm

Answer (score 1):

I have found Biblos Interlinear Bible to be an excellent resource.  There are also tabs across the top which can take you to other resources for a verse such as a listing of different translations or commentaries on the verse.

http://interlinearbible.org/genesis/1-1.htm

The New English Translation has a lot more of the in depth footnotes like you are describing which explain the translations.

Here's a good side-by-side reader.

http://net.bible.org/#!bible/Genesis+1

If you want to get hardcore with it, try out the Online Greek Interlinear Bible.  There's also a Hebrew one for the Old Testament.

http://www.scripture4all.org/OnlineInterlinear/Greek_Index.htm

Comment: The OT version for that is in Hebrew. However, isn't parts of the book of Ezra originally written in Aramaic instead of Hebrew (which was the version they used for their inter-linear)? http://www.christiananswers.net/dictionary/chaldeelanguage.html

Comment: Daniel, not Ezra, is partly in Aramaic.  Hebrew Bible editions show those portions in Aramaic.

Comment: @user116, https://www.christiancourier.com/articles/200-languages-of-the-bible claims Ezra 4:8-6:18; 7:12-26; Jeremiah 10:11; Daniel 2:46-7:28; and two words in Genesis 31:47 are aramaic.